# ValidationError themeConfig.hideableSidebar has been moved to themeConfig.docs.sidebar.hideable

Tags: javascript, node.js, documentation, docusaurus

I am getting this error:

```
[INFO] Starting the development server...
[ERROR] ValidationError: themeConfig.hideableSidebar has been moved to themeConfig.docs.sidebar.hideable.
[INFO] Docusaurus version: 2.4.1
Node version: v18.16.1
```

When I execute: "npm run start" intending to create a localhost for my documentation in docussaurus.

I already tried to change the themeConfig region of my file: docusaurus.config.js

was like this

```
themeConfig:
{
hideableSidebar: true,
autoCollapseCategories: true,
}
```

I switched to this form (hoping for salvation), using the help of chatGpt:

```
docs: {
   sidebar: {
   hideable: true,
   autoCollapseCategories: true,
  },
},
```

and nothing has changed.

I need your help or I will be fired.